# Creating a hyper service with custom error type

Tags: rust, hyper

I am trying to create a REST server using hyper. For robust error handling, I would prefer to have the service return a future with a custom error type that wraps hyper, Diesel, and other errors. Unfortunately, `hyper::Response` seems to hard-code a stream with error type `hyper::error::Error`, which conflicts with the error type I've defined for my service. I see a couple possible solutions:

1. Make my service return my custom error type by modifying `hyper::Response`, which seems hard.
2. Wrap non-hyper errors in a `hyper::error::Error`. This seems hacky.
3. Something else. It seems like I'm missing the "right" way to do this.

The following code shows what I think I want to do:

```
extern crate diesel;
extern crate futures;
extern crate hyper;

use futures::future::{ok, Future};
use hyper::StatusCode;
use hyper::server::{Request, Response, Service};

fn main() {
    let address = "127.0.0.1:8080".parse().unwrap();
    let server = hyper::server::Http::new()
        .bind(&address, move || Ok(ApiService {}))
        .unwrap();
    server.run().unwrap();
}

pub struct ApiService;

impl Service for ApiService {
    type Request = Request;
    type Response = Response;
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = Box<Future<Item = Self::Response, Error = Self::Error>>;

    fn call(&self, request: Request) -> Self::Future {
        Box::new(ok(Response::new().with_status(StatusCode::Ok)))
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Error {
    Request(hyper::Error),
    DatabaseResult(diesel::result::Error),
    DatabaseConnection(diesel::ConnectionError),
    Other(String),
}

// omitted impl of Display, std::error::Error for brevity
```

This code results in a compiler error which I believe is because the `bind` function requires that the response type have a body that is a stream with error type `hyper::error::Error`:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<ApiService as hyper::client::Service>::Error == hyper::Error`
  --> src/main.rs:14:10
   |
14 |         .bind(&address, move || Ok(ApiService {}))
   |          ^^^^ expected enum `Error`, found enum `hyper::Error`
   |
   = note: expected type `Error`
              found type `hyper::Error`
```

Answer (score 6):

Because the ultimate goal of the server is to return a response to the user, I found an acceptable solution to be to create a `finalize` function that converts errors encountered while processing a request into correctly formed responses and treats those errors as non-errors from hyper's perspective. I will need to flesh this idea out some (e.g. By passing along hyper errors as errors), but I believe the basic idea is sound.

The following code modifies the code in the question to do this:

```
extern crate diesel;
extern crate futures;
extern crate hyper;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use futures::future::{ok, Future};
use hyper::StatusCode;
use hyper::server::{Request, Response, Service};

fn main() {
    let address = "127.0.0.1:8080".parse().unwrap();
    let server = hyper::server::Http::new()
        .bind(&address, move || Ok(ApiService {}))
        .unwrap();
    server.run().unwrap();
}

fn finalize(result: Result<Response, Error>) -> FutureResult<Response, hyper::Error> {
    match result {
        Ok(response) => ok(response),
        Err(error) => {
            let response_body =
                json!({"status": 500, "description": error.description()}).to_string();
            ok(Response::new()
                .with_status(StatusCode::InternalServerError)
                .with_header(ContentLength(response_body.len() as u64))
                .with_body(response_body))
        }
    }
}

pub struct ApiService;

impl Service for ApiService {
    type Request = Request;
    type Response = Response;
    type Error = hyper::Error;
    type Future = Box<Future<Item = Self::Response, Error = Self::Error>>;

    fn call(&self, request: Request) -> Self::Future {
        let response = Ok(Response::new().with_status(StatusCode::Ok));
        Box::new(finalize(response))
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Error {
    Request(hyper::Error),
    DatabaseResult(diesel::result::Error),
    DatabaseConnection(diesel::ConnectionError),
    Other(String),
}

// omitted impl of Display, std::error::Error for brevity
```

Answer (score -3):

You can implement the [`std::convert::From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) trait for your `Error` type. E.g. for the `hyper::Error` case:

```
impl From<hyper::Error> for Error {
    fn from(error: hyper::Error) -> Self {
        Error::Request(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this addresses the original problem. This allows converting from Hyper's error to the user's error, but the problem is the other way around — the code needs to return Hyper's error and the user's error is being returned. Could you [edit] your answer to show how this works in the context of the original code?

Comment: Reading the provided compiler error, I got it the other way round: I.e. the code needs to return the user's error type but actually returns Hyper's error type.